# Joomla - Flexicontent Tags as keywords

Tags: joomla, keyword

Is there a way to set all the tags for an article as  the meta keywords for that article?

we have this working on one of our project but i cant seem to figure out how

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to retrieve the tags from Flexicontent - check with them to see how. Then you'd set the keywords using the setMetaData method of JDocument object: http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/setMetaData